# AWS Lambda function to scan/query DynamoDB table using array values as FilterExpression

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

here's my case: I'm trying to make a query on a table (table name `HCI.LocCatApp`) using a value sent by API as `KeyConditionExpression`, and I'm storing the results (which must be numbers not strings) in an array, and I want to use each value from this array as a `FilterExpression` to scan another table (table name `HCI.Category`) .. So what I need is to loop on the array values, take each of them as `FilterExpression` and perform the `scan` operation. I'm currently trying to use `IN` but I'm not sure if it's even supported or not.
And keep in mind that the array is being filled during the runtime. And the `callback` can be performed only once.

here's my code:

```
'use strict'

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var mydocumentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {

    var params = {
        TableName: 'HCI.LocCatApp',
        KeyConditionExpression : 'LocID = :lid',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":lid": event.LocID
        },
        ProjectionExpression: 'CatID'

    };
    var catIDs = [];
    var catIDsObject = {};
    var index = 0;

    mydocumentClient.query(params, function (err, data){
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        }else{
          data.Items.forEach(function(item){catIDs.push(item.CatID)});
          //callback(null, catIDs);

        }
    })

    catIDs.forEach(function(value){
      index ++;
      var catIDsKey = ":catID"+index;
      catIDsObject[catIDsKey] = value;
    })


      var params2 = {
        TableName: 'HCI.Category',
        FilterExpression : "CatID IN (:cIDs)",
        ExpressionAttributeValues : {
          ':cIDs' : catIDs
        }

      };
      mydocumentClient.scan(params2, function (err, data){
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        }else{
          callback(null, data);
        }
    })

}
```

For some reason, the current code runs successfully but it doesn't find any matches, even if I fill in the values manually in the array, there's still no results, the `IN` operation doesn't seem to work.
And many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `catIds` is an array of IDs (strings probably).

When you pass it to FilterExpression, you are assuming that it will be converted to a) string b) to a string in correct format.

```
FilterExpression : "CatID IN (:cIDs)",
        ExpressionAttributeValues : {
          ':cIDs' : catIDs
        }
```

I cannot try this myself at the moment, but I'm assuming this is where the query fails. `IN` operator expects a comma separated list of values to compare to, in parenthesis. So, after the array is inserted to query, it should be like this

```
FilterExpression : "CatID IN (cat1, cat2, cat2)",
```

But most probably it contains extra set of `[` and `]`, and maybe even the array to string conversion causes it to something like `[Object object]` etc.

One solution would be to use [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to concatenate all the elements from the array to single string before passing it to FilterExperession. Something like this

```
 FilterExpression : "CatID IN (:cIDs)",
            ExpressionAttributeValues : {
              ':cIDs' : catIDs.join()
            }
```

Comment: In fact, I'm just creating `catIDs` and as you can see I'm using `catIDs.push(item.CatID)` to put values in the array, the values are integers, and I'm trying to use them again in the next FilterExpression as integers, but I'm not sure if that is happening or it's just taking them as strings. And I'm using `IN` because it's the only thing I could come up with, but since I don't have predefined values like to be used like `"CatID IN (cat1, cat2, cat2)"` and since the array `catIDs` doesn't have a fixed size,so I must (somehow) iterate on all the values in the array and use each one individually

Comment: In other words, how can I use the values from the array as Integers one by one as FilterExpression .. that's what I'm looking for .. and thank you

Comment: @Merovingian I edited the answer and added a specified example of what I meant. If that does not work, you can iterate over the array and construct the whole `FilterExpression` string manually. This is plain JavaScript problem, unrelated to DynamoDB.

Comment: I've been trying to work on it for a quite long time already and I came up to a conclusion (maybe!) DynamoDB won't be the best solution to my use case, join operation are rather complex here, and I tried the solution you proposed (iterate over the array) and for some reason I was getting results sometimes and sometimes not, so I just decided to move to RDS. Thank you so much for your contribution.

Comment: @Merovingian Sorry to hear that you never got it working. TBH, now that I finally got a chance to try it, I could not nail the correct syntax either. Just can't figure out what is wrong... I'm guessing the `ExpressionAttributeValues` needs to be used and it should contain the data type that is being fetched