# Aws Lambda to read the user input dynamically and return the data from Dynamo table

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, dynamodb-queries

Lambda provides the expected result only when I pass the value manually (Id = '011010').

In the step function the value "ID" value will be random based on the logic from previous step, since the Id value is not static how to handle this scenario "ExpressionAttributeValues"

I tried all the below syntax but no luck..

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value':  $.External.Id}   
ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value':  External.Id.$}   
ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value':  $.Id}   
ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value':  Id.$}   
ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value':  event.Id}
```

**Lambda-Code**

```
   'use strict'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

 
var params = {
 TableName: 'temptable',
 IndexName: 'Id-CurrentStatus-index',
 KeyConditionExpression: '#Id= :value',
 ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#Id': 'Id'},
 ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value': 'M1' }
       
};

async function queryItems(){
 try {
   const data = await docClient.query(params).promise()
   return data
 } catch (err) {
   return err
 }
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
 try {
   const data = await queryItems()
   return { body: JSON.stringify(data) }
 } catch (err) {
   return { error: err }
 }
}
```

I can read it from the

```
   console.log("Memberid :" + JSON.stringify(event.Id, null, 2))
```

but how to pass the same value in the

```
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value': 'M1' }
```

I tried the below syntax. nothing works

```
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value': JSON.stringify(event.Id, null, 2) }
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value': event.Id}
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value': event.Id}
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value': Id}
```

Comment: Try adding `.$` to the end of the property you are trying to see. `ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value.$':  $.External.Id}`

Comment: Response: "body": "{\"message\":\"ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: \\\":value.$\\\"\

Comment: Any Help Folks?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Can you show the step input? If this is not an express step function you can view it in the console. For express functions you need to turn on logging.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth  This is not an express function. console.log works but but I'm not sure how-to pass inside  ExpressionAttributeValues, I have updated the question with some additional investigation. Please check. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the value is in `event.Id` then `ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value': event.Id }` should work. If it's not then can you provide more information? What is the error you are getting? What does the table definition look like? Some sample data would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the required code after checking multiple thread.

[AWS Lambda function to scan/query DynamoDB table using array values as FilterExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56884833/aws-lambda-function-to-scan-query-dynamodb-table-using-array-values-as-filterexp)

```
'use strict'

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var mydocumentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {

    var params = {
        TableName: 'temptable',
        KeyConditionExpression : 'Id= :Id',
        FilterExpression : 'Id in (:Id)',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":Id": event.Id
        }

    };
    
      
      mydocumentClient.scan(params, function (err, data){
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        }else{
          callback(null, data);
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: You should avoid using the `scan` operation for most use cases. It certainly isn't something you want to use to get a small set of data from your table.

Comment: Thanks, but that's the only option available

Comment: Have you considered adding a GSI to the table? For the simple expression you are using that would be far more efficient.